# HouseHolder Transformation-QR Decomposition

Tags: matrix, fortran, qr-decomposition

I am working on QR factorization, the code is working here but my problem is, for example, there is an array `dimension(6,4)` but I want to decompose `dimension(6,2)`. I use the subroutine(`dgeqrf`) so Should I use a different one or not? That subroutine is taking the whole matrix but I want to give a different column size because I can decompose the matrix `(6,2)`. I share current result for this program but I want for `(6,2)` dimension decomposition not `(6,4)` dimension

```
!Current result:          but I want:
! x x x x                  x x x x
! 0 x x x                  0 x x x
! 0 0 x x                  0 0 x x
! 0 0 0 x                  0 0 x x
! 0 0 0 0                  0 0 x x
! 0 0 0 0                  0 0 x x

 program decomposition

 !CONTAINS
 !subroutine Qrdecomposition(A_mat, R)

 real(8),dimension(6,4)   :: A_mat    
 !real,dimension(2,2),intent(inout)
 real(8),dimension(6,4)   :: R        
 !real,dimension(2,2),intent(out)
 real(8),dimension(6,4)                  :: A
 integer                              :: M,N,LDA,LWORK,INFO,i,j
 real(8),allocatable, dimension(:,:)     :: TAU
 real(8),allocatable, dimension(:,:)     :: WORK
 external   dgeqrf
 M=6
 N=4
 LDA=6
 LWORK=4
 INFO=0
 A_mat(1,:)=[2,1,2,6 ]
 A_mat(2,:)=[10,4,3,2]
 A_mat(3,:)=[1,3,2,9]
 A_mat(4,:)=[8,9,2,7]
 A_mat(5,:)=[9,5,9,4]
 A_mat(6,:)=[9,10,6,6]

A=A_mat

allocate(tau(M,N), work(M,N))
call dgeqrf(M,N,A,LDA,TAU,WORK,LWORK,INFO)
R=A
R(:,:)=0
do i=1,6
do j=i,4
    R(i,j)=A(i,j)
end do
end do

print *,R

!end subroutine Qrdecomposition
end program decomposition 
!Input
!A =
! 2     1     2     6
!10     4     3     2
! 1     3     2     9
! 8     9     2     7
! 9     5     9     4
! 9    10     6     6
 !The result should be like that
 !  -18.193      -13.851      -10.278      -10.278
 !       0        6.336     0.099656       6.5706
 !       0            0      0.64881       5.2419
 !       0            0       -3.887      -3.5114
 !       0            0       4.0589      -1.1447
 !       0            0      -0.5819      -5.6624
```

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark they are just same things, 'A_mat and A' are same input(6,4) dimension.

Comment: I also do not understand what you are asking. Also, I removed your fortran90 and 95 tags, because your program is actually Fortran 2003,  at least the array constructor syntax `[]`. Also note that `real(8)` is ugly and not portable.

Comment: I updated the question, I think it is clear now. Sorry for different syntax but I just did for example

Comment: I still don't understand what you need. You want a different result from the external function? Because if that's it, I think you will need to crunch the math behind that and change the array before or after passing through the function to yeld the result you want.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues Actually, yes, This subroutine is not available for my aim. Or I need different subroutine and I checked `lapack` but i didnt find it.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what you want. If I had to guess I would say simply setting N to 2 will do what you want - is it simply that you want to decompose part of A and not all of A?

Comment: @IanBush It is not possible set 2 in `dgeqrf` subroutine because this subroutine needs dimension of input array so input array column is 4. I think `dgeqrf` subroutine is not possible to solve this.

Comment: Note that in dgetrf you supply the `LDA` argument precisely because the array can be defined inside a larger array. That used to be typical in FORTRAN 77 where all arrays where static. You had a static array `A(MAX_N, MAX_M)` and used just some part of it.

Comment: Thanks guys for comment, I solved the problem. I wrote house holder transformation myself and it is working. I will share the code next days :)